# Microsoft Outlook VPN into Microsoft Exchange 2007

Tags: vpn, exchange, exchange-2007, microsoft-office-2013

I am having difficulty connecting to my Exchange server 2007 over VPN when using Outlook 2013 in a Windows 7 Pro environment. What has me totally baffled is that I can connect just fine from a Windows XP Pro machine running Outlook 2003 in the same office. I verified the settings on both machines and they are identical. Both VPN successfully connect. When it comes to creating my exchange mail account in Outlook 2013  however, I get the message that "Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action".

Comment: Ask your administrator? No information given besides what a user would give, so I assume you are not a professional admin and that is - the group we serve here.

Comment: Why are you not using Outlook Anywhere?

Comment: What more would you like TomTom. And, by the way, I am the admin. I was merely trying to keep my question short-winded. Much like your response I'm afraid !!! Thanks for nothing.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thank you for the promt reply. I took over this account a few weeks ago. My client has staff that travel extensively. The laptops that they have been provided do not have any browsers installed. That is how the owner wants things to be. So, for now I am stuck with some machines running Outlook 2003 and newer ones running Outlook 2013. As I said eralier I can access mail via VPN into SBS 2011 just fine on some but no luck with Outlook 2013.

Comment: Can you connect using Outlook 2013 at all? If not check if you have all updates for Outlook and Exchange installed.

Comment: @lsmooth As I said in my earlier post, I cannot connect to our Exchange 2010 using Outlook 2013. My O/S including all Office suite modules are up to date. What has me stumped, is that I can connect to our exchange server just fine over VPN from a desktop running Windows XP and Outlook 2003. This, no one has been able to demystify.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2003 doesn't support autodiscover.  Outlook 2007 and above--including Outlook 2013--does.

It's hard to say based on the information provided, but I would suggest you look at your autodiscover settings and make certain that what's being provided to 2013 is something that can be resolved over VPN.

Comment: "Autodiscover", not autoconfigure. But I have no doubt this is right on the money.